# 'ng2-pnotify' is not found - angular2

Tags: angular

I installed npm package pnotify for angular 2 by putting
"ng2-pnotify": "0.0.3",

in package.json and clicking on restore packages. I am now able to see np2-notify in node-modules and in dependencies.

I am including import { PNotifySettings } from 'ng2-pnotify';in this app.module.ts but it says 'ng2-pnotify' is not found. How to resolve this?

Comment: what angular version do u use 2 or 4?

Comment: I am currently using 2.

Comment: it requires 2.0.0-rc.4 -too old